# How can I get VisualStudio 2010 with ReSharper to preserve my spaces between '<%:', content, and '%>'?

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio-2010, coding-style, resharper

I have Visual Studio 2010 and ReSharper installed and after looking for about an hour, I can't find this formatting setting anywhere.

I'd like it to look like this:

```
<div><%: Model.Something %></div>
```

and it keeps removing my space between `Model.Something` and `%>` to look like this:

```
<div><%: Model.Something%></div>
```

Comment: What version of ReSharper do you use?

Comment: Good question. 6.0 Full Edition, build 6.0.2202.688.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

This behavior would be fixed in the next EAP of ReSharper 6.1, maybe even in beta. Sorry, had no time for an option - for 6.1 there would be spaces always, hopefully most of ASP.NET developers would like it that way.

P.S. In older versions you can switch it via option ReSharper | Options | Languages | C# | Formatting Style | Spaces -> Within parentheses -> Method call parentheses. But switching it also affects C# method calls.

Answer (score 0):

I've had some success with the Solution-based settings...

ReSharper -> Options -> Languages -> C# -> Formatting Style -> Spaces

There is no equivalent section for ASP.Net or HTML, but it seems to take some from the actual code language your asp.net pages are written in... so try the C# section.

Comment: Thanks, I just looked there again just in case. Didn't see one. Unless it's cryptically reusing one of those, there isn't a spacing option that resembles anything close to ASP.NET notation in there.

Comment: Maybe the "multiplicative operators" checkbox even though its not an operator in ASP.Net?

Comment: Yeah, I already have that turned on to add spaces between them. I turned it off just to compare and nothing.

Comment: Bummer. Ask their support group. Phone calls work good too. ;)